# Loading Html file in WebView in xaml in UWP from app data local folder

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a requirement where I need to load an html file from app data folder in xaml WebView in UWP. Html file is also referencing different Js files in another  folder ("99/js/"). Any one with UWP knowledge guide me. Thanks in advance
I am using following code, `Browser` is my WebView.

```
  var Uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/Downloads/99/index.html");
  Browser.Navigate(Uri);
```

My folder structure in 99 folder is:
[image]
**udapte**
I am trying load html file in offline to WebView which is not loading same html file is loading with server url.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Html file is not loading in offline in webview.You can see our folder structure in the above i am trying to load index.html

Answer (score 12):

To load the `index.html` in `WebView` while offline, you need to make sure all the resource used in `index.html` are correctly located in app's [LocalFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder). And **all these content must be placed in a subfolder under the local folder**.

Ref **Remarks** in [WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview):

> To load uncompressed and unencrypted content from your app’s [**LocalFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) or [**TemporaryFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder) data stores, use the [**Navigate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate) method with a [**Uri**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri) that uses the [**ms-appdata scheme**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406#ms_appdata). The **WebView** support for this scheme **requires you to place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder.** This enables navigation to URIs such as ms-appdata:///local/*folder/file.html* and ms-appdata:///temp/*folder/file.html* . (To load compressed or encrypted files, see [**NavigateToLocalStreamUri**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri).)

For example, I created a simple `index.html` that use `index.js` in `js` folder and `index.css` in `css` folder.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <button id="myBtn">Click Me!</button>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += "You have clicked once! <br>";
    }
}
```

**index.css**

```
#myDiv {
    border: 2px dotted black;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

They located in my app's LocalFolder like following:
[image]

Then in my UWP app, I used following code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="Browser" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Browser.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/Downloads/index.html"));
}
```

This works well:
[image]
So if your html file  is not loading, please check your app's LocalFolder and make sure your html file and the resources are located in right place.

On Local Machine, the data files are stored in the folder

> **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageId}**

which usually is ***C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Packages\{PackageId}***, where **`{UserName}`** corresponds to the Windows user name and **`{PackageId}`** corresponds to the Windows Store application package identifier which you can find as **`Package family name`** in **Packaging** tab of your app's manifest file. The **LocalState** folder inside the package folder is the LocalFolder.

For Mobile Emulator, we can use some tools like [IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) or [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to check the LocalFolder.

If you can load the html file, but some resources are missing like missing the css style, you may need to check your html code and make sure the references are right.

Comment: You can also place the files at [other locations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28227571/426227). But this approach doesn't seem to work for xml with xsl files ...