# Loading page relative to local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to show a web page relative to the local folder in a UWP app. This means, I have the page itself as string, but assets (images, scripts) are located in the apps local folder.

I tried to use the `NavigateToString` method that as I understood should serve this task, in combination with the `Source`-property of a `WebView` control.

```
var baseUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/");
WebView.Source = baseUri;
var page = ...;
WebView.NavigateToString(page);
```

However, this gives me the following error message when assigning the `Source`-property of the web view:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in App.exe
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

So apparently, using the local app folder for assets is not supported?

The app targets minimum Windows 10 Build 10586.

Does anybody know whether there is a useful workaround for this?

**Edit:** I tried to make a minimum example. In the following, I created a small test app that does nothing but loading a static html file from the local storage. As far as I can tell, this code exactly resembles the [XamlWebView example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView) but does raise an ArgumentException.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView Name="WebView" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Initialize();
        }

        private async void Initialize()
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("index.html", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("<html>");
                sw.WriteLine("<body>");
                sw.WriteLine("This is some text");
                sw.WriteLine("</body>");
                sw.WriteLine("</html>");
            }

            WebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/index.html"));
        }
    }
}
```

I do not even know where the difference to the sample is, can't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebView.Source property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.source) is ued to gets or sets the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) source of the HTML content to display in the WebView control.
We usually set the `Source` property in XAML. The XAML parser automatically converts the string to a [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri). The `Source` property can be set in code, but rather than doing so, we typically use one of the **Navigate** methods such as [Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate), [NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring) and [NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatewithhttprequestmessage) method to load content in code.

And the URI you've used in your code is not a valid URI for WebView control, so you got a `Value does not fall within the expected range.` error. To load content from app’s local storage, we need to **place the content in a subfolder under the local folder**. Ref **Remarks** in [WebView class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview):

> To load uncompressed and unencrypted content from your app’s [**LocalFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder) or [**TemporaryFolder**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.temporaryfolder) data stores, use the [**Navigate**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigate) method with a [**Uri**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri) that uses the [**ms-appdata scheme**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406#ms_appdata). The **WebView** support for this scheme requires you to place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder. This enables navigation to URIs such as ms-appdata:///local/*folder/file.html* and ms-appdata:///temp/*folder/file.html* . (To load compressed or encrypted files, see [**NavigateToLocalStreamUri**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri).)
>
> Each of these first-level subfolders is isolated from the content in other first-level subfolders. For example, you can navigate to ms-appdata:///temp/folder1/file.html, but you can’t have a link in this file to ms-appdata:///temp/folder2/file.html. However, you can still link to HTML content in the app package using the **ms-appx-web** scheme, and to web content using the **http** and **https** URI schemes.

So when you use `WebView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/index.html"));`, you still get the error as `ms-appdata:///local/index.html` is also not a valid URI for WebView.

Besides, although [NavigateToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring) supports content with references to external files such as CSS, scripts, images, and fonts. But it only supports content in the app package using the **ms-appx-web** scheme, and web content using the **http** and **https** URI schemes. It can't work with assets located in the apps local folder. To achieve what you want you need to put these assets into a subfolder under the local folder and then also store the html string to a file under the same subfolder. In the html, you can use relative URI to reference these assets like what in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792017/5506161).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I object that `ms-appdata:///local/index.html` is not a valid URI. It may be a URI that the WebView cannot handle, but it is nevertheless a valid URI (even `foo:///bar/` is a valid URI).

Comment: @Georg Yeah, you are right. Here I mean not a valid URI for WebView control. I've edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.