# Display local html file content in UWP WebView

Tags: c#, webview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I believe this is pretty straightforward task and I've seen a lot of examples in the web but still none of them is working for me since I experience different exceptions.

**html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        Help html content.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**xaml:**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <WebView x:Name="webView" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonRefresh" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Click="buttonRefresh_Click">
            Refresh
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

To display static html saved in `help.html` file in my UWP application LocalFolder I've already tried the following:

- **Use Navigate method:**

```
private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/help.html");
            webView.Navigate(uri);
        }
```

and the result is the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.Navigate(Uri source)
   at SimpleUwpApp.Proxy.SimplerPage.buttonRefresh_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

**- Try to set Source property of webView explicitly in code behind:**

```
private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var uri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/help.html");
    webView.Source = uri;
}
```

result:

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.put_Source(Uri value)
   at SimpleUwpApp.Proxy.SimplerPage.buttonRefresh_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

**- Set Source property of webView explicitly in xaml:** This is the exact example from [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView).

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="ms-appdata:///local/help.html" />
```

As a result exception on startup:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.Source' because the type 'Windows.Foundation.String' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.Foundation.Uri'. [Line: 16 Position: 54]
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at SimpleUwpApp.Proxy.SimplerPage.InitializeComponent()
```

**- Tried using url string directly in `Navigate()` arguments as in this [microsoft examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_Navigate_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) but `Navigate()` accepts only `Uri` as an aargument so the documentation is either invalid, either for older version of xaml toolkit.**

```
webView.Navigate("ms-appx-web:///help.html");
```

result:

```
Syntax error.
```

The only solution I've temporary came up with is reading the content of html file with some kind of file manager and using `NavigateToString()` method:

```
var content = fileManager.Read("help.html"); // Manually read the content of html file
webView.NavigateToString(content);
```

**So the question is why described examples don't work? How to avoid using NavigateToString?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading Html file in WebView in xaml in UWP from app data local folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626840/loading-html-file-in-webview-in-xaml-in-uwp-from-app-data-local-folder)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution [provided by TheTanic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42418783/2681948) will work for files that are delivered with your package. For files stored in your *LocalFolder* or *TemporaryFolder* you must [follow special URI scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView):

> The WebView support for this scheme requires you to place your content in a subfolder under the local or temporary folder. This enables navigation to Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) such as ms-appdata:///local/folder/file.html and ms-appdata:///temp/folder/file.html

This means that if you use *LocalFolder* then URI will start like this: `ms-appdata:///local/` after this **must** be a folder and inside your file. Here is a working sample:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///help.html"));
StorageFolder folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("anyFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await file.CopyAsync(folder, "help.html", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
webView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/anyFolder/help.html"));
```

Note also that all the content used must be also in that folder as:

> Each of these first-level subfolders is isolated from the content in other first-level subfolders.

Comment: Yes, it was the case. I just moved the file to a subfolder and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

So i got two different things, which worked for me:

The XAML-version:

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Source="ms-appx-web:///help.html"/>
```

Here you need to use the `ms-appx-web` prefix.

The code-behind version:

```
webView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///help.html"));
```

The difference to your version is, that you are not allowed to enter the string only. You need to create a new Object of the `Uri`-Class.

In both versions, the `html`-file is a direct child of the project and the project is a `Windows-10-UWP Application` [You didnt say, if you use Windows 8 or Windows 10]